# mysql update column in a table return error unknown column

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name =
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT col FROM tab WHERE id = `My ID`) UNION table_2)
WHERE `My ID` = 123;
```

However, it doesn't work. It says `My ID` is unknown column in WHERE clause. What I want to do is to use `My ID` column in table_name, to join 2 other tables and count row number of that UNION table.

Please let me know how can I make it work. Thanks!

Comment: In order to work ´My ID’ should be in table_name.

Comment: @XavierBouclet `My ID` is indeed in table_name, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it present in tab? And please give us more info about the dbms used and the spécificité error. And you should avoid space in columns.

Comment: @XavierBouclet Yes it is in tab because I have a space. The error says Error Code 1054: unknown column My ID in where clause

Comment: Try to specify the table on each ‘my id’. table_name.´my id’. May be Mysql can’t choose which ´my id’. So forcing the table will Yelp.

Comment: @XavierBouclet I tried that but it doesn't work. I feel that the outside query doesn't know what is in select count(*) from ... if I don't use count, instead just call a column from that union table it will work. But I want to count the row number of union table and send it to the table_name ...

Comment: So add the column ´my id’ near the count(*). Count(*),’my id’

Comment: @XavierBouclet But `My ID` doesn't below to those 3 inside tables. I use `My ID` from the table_name to query specific rows from those 3 tables ...

Comment: Ok so the pb is the ´my id’ = 123 you can’t do that if it doesn’t belong to table_name.

Comment: @XavierBouclet `My ID` belong to table_name. But it returns error when I run it. It says `My ID` is unknown.

Comment: @Sean column names from outer tables are not visible to a subquery nested two levels down. Correlation can only be one level deep.  I would try to answer this, but your `UNION` (which is implicitly a `UNION DISTINCT` in modern versions of MySQL Server) doesn't seem sensible with no `WHERE` clause for table_2, so it's not clear what the query is actually supposed to be counting.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It is supposed to count row number of the union of 3 tables